# Mouseout is not woking properly(jquery)

Tags: jquery

I am trying to trigger both event on one element.mouseover is working fine but its not working for mouse out.please suggest me if i am missing something.

```
$(".edit_title_section").mouseover(function(){
    $("#link_title").addClass("link_title_highlight");
    $(".edit_title_section").show();
});
$(".edit_title_secttion").mouseout(function(){
    alert("check alert");
});
```

Answer (score 5):

There's a typo in the selector:

```
 // $(".edit_title_secttion") - 2 't's in 'secttion`, there should be 1:
 $(".edit_title_section")....
```

Better yet, hook both events of the same selector;

```
$(".edit_title_section")
    .mouseover(function() {
        $("#link_title").addClass("link_title_highlight");
        $(".edit_title_section").show();
    })
    .mouseout(function() {
        alert("check alert");
    });
```